# SQL UPDATE , SELECT CASE with Division and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried a lot way to do but not works any one , I need to update t1 only if in the t2 the division betwwen t1.total and t1.quantity is un range in t2

My code:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Code_142 = 'OK' 
SELECT CASE WHEN quantity = 0 THEN NULL ELSE TOTAL/quantity END AS q
FROM Servicios_de_control_de_calidad_de_agua_potable as t1
INNER JOIN Con_A as t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.q BETWEEN t2.Mins AND t2.Maxs
```

Regards

Comment: i dont think you can have Select in the update clause

Comment: can you provide more details? Table structure and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query you are looking for should be like below

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Code_142 = 'OK' 
FROM Servicios_de_control_de_calidad_de_agua_potable  t1
INNER JOIN Con_A  t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE CASE WHEN quantity = 0 THEN t2.Mins-1 ELSE TOTAL/quantity END BETWEEN t2.Mins AND t2.Maxs
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Try as per following, May it help you

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Code_142 = 'OK' 
FROM Servicios_de_control_de_calidad_de_agua_potable as t1
INNER JOIN Con_A as t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (CASE WHEN quantity = 0 THEN NULL ELSE TOTAL/quantity END) BETWEEN t2.Mins AND t2.Maxs
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I can not test this code, but you might need this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Code_142 = 'OK',
    q = CASE WHEN quantity = 0 THEN NULL ELSE TOTAL/quantity END 
FROM Servicios_de_control_de_calidad_de_agua_potable as t1
INNER JOIN Con_A as t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.q BETWEEN t2.Mins AND t2.Maxs
```